# Handle ngrx effect catchError properly

Tags: angular, ngrx

Hello I have an Effect and want to handle error properly. I want to call an additional action with content of my server side error. How could I do this?

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthEffects {
    @Effect()
    registerUser$ = this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthActions.Action.CREATE_USER),
      switchMap(({user}) =>
        this.customersService.createNewUser(user).pipe(
          switchMap(() => [
            new ModalActions.SetModalType(null)
            ]
          ),
            catchError((err) => {
              if (foo) {
              new ModalActions.SetModalErrors(err.error); // <---- make an Action here
              } else {
              }
              return throwError(err);
            })

            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: Have you tried `return of(new ModalActions.SetModalErrors(...))` ?

Comment: @AndreiGătej sure, it works. But I need to check if it is a error.foo in response and if it is I need to add notification, or add another action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately nobody answered, but anyway this works:

```
catchError((err) => {
  if (err.error.email) {
    return of(new ModalActions.SetModalErrors(err.error));
  } else {
  this.notificationService.notify(Object.values(err.error)[0] as string);
  return throwError(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: `return throwError(err);`  that would keep your effect running for a few most retries and that it would stop. Make sure you are handling all of your errors in effects completely and not pushing them further.

Comment: @AlexOkrushko thank you. Is it better to return empty []?

Comment: it would have to return either an Action (with or without the payload) OR `EMPTY` Observable.

Comment: Just a note:
Ommitting the „return throwError()“ would your (maybe used) custom error handler not to be called, right?

I would just call the next action in you if-statement  which could be named like „AuthActions.Action.CREATE_USER_FAILED“ (do not forget to use „dispatch: false“ there).
Then, in your failure action, you can do whatever you want without ending in an action loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you return the result of `throwError()` from catchError, you should be able to simply return array of actions in the other case

```
      catchError((err) => {
        if (foo) {
          // whatever you return here, should be an Observable-ish thing
          // an Observable of(), an array, etc
          return [
            new ModalActions.SetModalErrors(err.error),
          ];
        } else {
          return throwError(err);
        }
      })
```